# Windows Service for monitoring clipboard usage

Tags: c#, windows, service, clipboard

I have a windows forms application that makes use of the Clipboard class.  My boss wants me to turn this into a windows service that can run in the background.  I get that services are not supposed to interact w/ the desktop but in this instance it makes sense to be a windows service.

```
 protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        // defined in winuser.h
        const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
        const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

        switch(m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                DisplayClipboardData();
                SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                break;

            case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                    nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
                else
                    SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }   
    }

    void DisplayClipboardData()     
    {
        try
        {
            IDataObject iData = new DataObject();
            iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection returnList = null;
            string entireCB = null;

            if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {

                if (Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList())
                {
                    returnList = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
                   // Clipboard.SetFileDropList(replacementList);
                }
               // return returnList;

            }
            if (returnList != null)
            {
                foreach (string item in returnList)
                {
                    entireCB = entireCB + "\"" + item + "\",\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt") + "\"," + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\CopiedFiles.csv", entireCB);
                //System.IO.File.Open(@"C:\temp\CopiedFiles.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Edit: we are doing this because we want to capture file copies of people trying to move confidential data.

Comment: I did not see anything related to ASP.Net. Did you tag it wrong?

Comment: So what is your question about ?

Comment: Yes I tagged it wrong.  It is a windows forms app that reads the contents of the clipboard.  I want it to be a windows service so that it can run in the background and build a report of what was copied and when.  If this is the wrong location for my question let me know and I'll move it.

Comment: Also, to add context my question is is it possible to make this work as a service?   I think the problem is reading the clipboard that belongs to someone else's desktop as the service or whatever will be running on a separate thread.